# jquery only passing dropdownbox highest value

Tags: php, jquery

i've got a dropdownbox which has values assigned to it, and i'm trying to retrieve that value and perform a .load function and return the value, but it didn't turned out as so, the value being retrieved is always the top of the dropdownlist no matter what is selected.

Here's my jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inputField= $('#dateslot').val();
  $("#dateslot").change(function(){
    $("#timeslot").load('check.php?dateselect='+inputField);
  });
});
</script>
```

While here's my dropdownbox

```
    <select name="dateslot" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" id="dateslot">
    <option value="notselected">SELECT A DATE</option>
    <?php

    for($i = 1; $i/31 != 1; $i++){
    $date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $vdate);
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+".$i." days"));

    $readdate = date('d F Y', strtotime($date2));
    echo '<option value="'.$date2.'">'.$readdate.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

in my check.php i got the dateselect using $_GET and found out that no matter what i select, the result is always notselected(which is the first option)

i tried stripping that code out, the value shown is still the first of the list, i tried taking out the php and use only the options, same result. any help =/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the value when the page loads, but not updating it when it changes.  I've just moved the `inputField` declaration to inside the change event handler...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dateslot").change(function() {
        var inputField= $(this).val();
        $("#timeslot").load("check.php?dateselect=" + inputField);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the value on initial page load. Try this instead

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dateslot").change(function(){
    var theField = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $("#timeslot").load('check.php?dateselect='+theField);
  });
});
</script>
```

This get's the value of the selected option when the select changes and then passes it to the load function.

Answer (score 0):

You are no retrieving value on change event of dropdown, hence it is always loading data based on default value of dropdown, try using below script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dateslot").change(function(){
    var inputField= $('#dateslot').val();
    $("#timeslot").load('check.php?dateselect='+inputField);
  });
});
</script>
```